# Python File Upload rename, Zip and save

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-upload, zip, file-rename

My requirement is

1. File upload,
2. Rename the file,
3. Compress it - make it as a zip,
4. Save in required location,
5. unzip the zip file,
6. Remove the zip file,
7. save the renamed file and filesize in DB

Renaming and zipping the file is not happening. Let me add my code here

```
@app.route('/temp/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']

        random_string = generate_random(5)
        print "Random string=> ", random_string # wqzhp
        print "f.filename->>> ", f.filename  # form3.pdf

        fn = f.filename
        fname = (fn).split(".")
        random_file_name = fname[0] + '-' + random_string + "." + fname[1]
        print "random_file_name>> ", random_file_name # form3-wqzhp.pdf

        actual_file = os.path.join(load_path, random_file_name)
        print "Actual file -> ", actual_file # uploadedDocs/1/form3-wqzhp.pdf

        zip_f_name = actual_file + ".zip"
        print "zip_f_name--> ", zip_f_name # uploadedDocs/1/form3-wqzhp.pdf.zip

        f.save(zip_f_name)
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_f_name, 'r')
        zip_ref.extractall(load_path)
        zip_ref.close()
        os.remove(zip_f_name)

        if update_file_status(random_file_name, 0, csvid) is False:
            return "update failed"
        return "success"
```

When the zip is extracted, only original file uploaded is unzipped.  zipping with the renamed file is not happening! How to save the renamed file in zip?

Any Clues!

Comment: As it is, your code will be very difficult to debug. Chop up the whole thing into smaller functions with well defined inputs and outputs and debug those individually.

Comment: Should probably use `fn.rsplit(".", 1)` and `with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_f_name, 'r') as zip_ref:` to be [more robust for errors](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile).